# Action not applying fully when importing model to Three.js

Tags: export, three.js, gltf

I have a simple character that I have rigged with an armature and created a Walk animation. I am very much in the learning-phase of how to do this.

I have exported the scene as a glTF so I can import into Three.js. However, when I do so, the Walk animation only appears to apply to some of the bones.

I have imported the model into [glTF Viewer](https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/) where I see the same issue. This suggests the problem is somewhere on my blender model and/or how I'm exporting it.

Here is how the walk cycle appears in Blender. Animated gif: http://g.recordit.co/iTbXdeNprB.gif

[image]

Here is how the model appears in glTF Viewer. The arms-out-wide is the armature's default pose. Animated gif: http://g.recordit.co/sgaKQBFXqc.gif

[image]

I am hoping someone can point to the obvious mistake I've made. I have used the default options in the glTF exporter - I can't see anything obvious in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have mentioned this was using Blender 2.80. Some further digging found this issue on the exporter: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/439

Having upgraded to Blender 2.81, which includes the fix for this issue, my model now imports correctly with the animation as I expected.

Comment: ^You may want to mark your answer as accepted here. :)